# Python class data initialization

Tags: python

I have a class like this

```
class Tree:
    # class attributes:
    a = []
    b = None

    def __init__(self, b, a_list):
        self.b = b
        if a_list is not None:
             initialize_a_list(a_list)
   
    def initialize_a_list(self, a_list):
        self.a.append(a_list)
```

When I make this call, `tree = Tree(b, None)`. My tree object's `a` attribute was not initialized with an empty list but a random non-empty list. Before that I've created some other object of type `Trees` and I notice some of the elements in `tree`'s `a` has the same elements as `a` of those objects created earlier.

I added `a = []` in the `__init__` function to the code to address the issue, but I was wondering why that was the case. Why was `a` initialized with such maybe-not-so-random but non-empty list.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: There's a comment indicating that `a` and `b` are class attributes. Do you understand the difference between class variables and instance variables?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thank you thank you! I just looked it up. I was applying the C++ syntax here.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables aren't supposed to be declared like:

```
class Tree:
    # class attributes:
    a = []
    b = None
```

Move those lines to the `__init__` constructor method, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Before that I've created some other object of type Trees and I notice some of the elements in tree's `a` has the same elements as `a` of those objects created earlier.

That is because you have declared the `a` variable as a class variable. This means that it is shared by all instances of the class, and the class itself.

Initializing the `a` variable in the `__init__` method causes it to be an instance variable, which means it is owned individually by each instance of the class (a separate data structure is allocated to and handled by each instance).

Lastly, it's worth noting that `a` was indeed initialized as an empty list, it's just that other `Tree` instances wrote to that shared list, causing it to appear as though it held random data.